# Spelling of בארי in the Rambam

Tags: words, hebrew, rambam, manuscripts, rav-nachum-rabinovitch

I noticed in several places in the text of the Rambam presented in Rav Nachum Rabinovitch's *Yad Peshuta* (e.g. in *hilchoth nachaloth*) that instead of the expected spelling/word "בריא" (a healthy person) he uses the word/spelling "בארי".  Is this an alternate spelling that existed in the medieval era that is present in the *kitvei yad* of the Rambam?